# Transparency in texture not working in libgdx

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I'm trying to draw a sprite in libgdx that has a transparent background to it, but the transparent background is filled in with white instead of showing what has already been rendered at that location.

[image: transparency doesn't show up]

The sprite (with the hat) is 64 by 64 with transparency around the edge and on the right. There should be two tiles with a 'C!' behind him but it's just filled in with white.

This is the code I am using to render the image.

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch sb, float parentAlpha){
    sb.enableBlending();
    sb.draw(texture, getX() + 32, getY());
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're going to enable blending, you *also* need to [set the blend function](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.htmlble) with `setBlendFunction`. This defines exactly how you want the blending to work. Presumably, you want the classic `GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` blending.

Comment: No luck. This code creates exactly the same image.

    public void draw(SpriteBatch sb, float parentAlpha){
      sb.enableBlending();
      sb.setBlendFunction(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
      sb.draw(texture, getX(), getY());
 }

Comment: @ScottJordan: Then your question doesn't contain all of the information needed to answer it. Either you're not drawing the image you think you are, the image doesn't have the transparency you think it does, the image has transparency but you're loading it incorrectly, or libgdx has a bug in it.

Answer (score 3):

All the sprites are supposed to be blended? Maybe disabling the blend after you already drawn could solve your problem.

Maybe something like that:

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch sb, float parentAlpha){
   sb.enableBlending();
   sb.draw(texture, getX() + 32, getY());
   sb.disableBlending();
}
```

If this doesn't work you could try activating the blend in the GL options with something like that:

```
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            ...
            Your code Here
            ...
    Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure your PNG has transparency information in it.

Second, make sure you're drawing things in the right order (you have to draw the background boxes *before* the sprite).

Comment: This solve it: make sure you're drawing things in the right order (you have to draw the background boxes before the sprite).

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the problem by changing my application to OpenGL 2.0 instead of 1.0. Still not sure what the problem was.